# Is it "less than" or "lesser than"?

Tags: comparative-constructions, comparative-degree

I often hear people say "less than", but shouldn't it be "lesser than"? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 19):

*Less*, *lesser*, and *littler* are all comparative forms of *little*. They are used like this:

- **little - littler - littlest** when you mean "small in size"
- **little - less - least** when you mean "small in amount"
- **little - lesser - least** when you mean "inferior or smaller in importance"

So if you mean one quantity or number is smaller than another, you say "less than".

Comment: The OED describes _littler_ and _littlest_ as ‘unrecognized forms’ and comments that they are ‘confined to dialect or imitations of childish or illiterate speech.’

Comment: I had never heard of a correct usage for *littler* or *littlest*; is it common practice in the States?

Comment: @Paola: maybe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgGKSjiw0HQ ?

Comment: @Paola: As Barrie noted, "littler" and "littlest" are really not proper words.

Comment: A children's book "The Littlest Angel" is allegedly the fifteenth best-selling children's book of all time.  (Look it up on Amazon.)  So, many children, at least in the US, have been misled for years if the OED is to be strictly believed.  (Usually I agree with the OED, but here I think they're a little too quick to pass judgment.)

Comment: As Barrie says, they're 'confined to ... imitations of childish ... speech' - _The Littlest Angel_ would be one such example.

Comment: As I can see in Merriam-webster dictionary, lesser means "of less size, quality, degree, or significance:  of lower status", which includes the meaning of "littler". Also, as per this dictionary, the definition for less has all the three meanings specified for littler, less, lesser.

Answer (score 0):

"Lesser than" would be incorrect since "lesser" and "than" both imply a comparison, which makes them redundant when used together. It would have to either be "less than" or "lesser" only.

Comment: "That cat is better than my dog"- seems alright to me. Then why not "That cat weighs lesser than my dog"

Comment: @Shreyans "Lesser" just doesn't mean that. We don't use it as a comparative for general qualities or quantities, only for importance. In your example sentence "less than" is definitely the correct choice. You could say that the cat is lesser than your dog, if you mean it is qualitatively worse in some objective way, but that would be a pretty weird thing to say since we don't really have an objective metric for comparing pets.

Comment: @amalloy I understand your point and completely agree, but the answer above our comments seems incorrect. Does "better" not "imply a comparison"?

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand the answer. "Greater than" is obviously a thing that is said, so it seems fine to have two words that "imply a comparison" work together. I think that's the point you were trying to make, but your conclusion makes it sound like you think "weighs lesser than" is okay. If your intent was to say that this answer's proposed rule can't be right and provide a counterexample, I would have stopped with the first sentence.

Comment: This sentence is from a dictionary. "Certainly, her love for him is LESSER than her love for her mother." What justification for its usage in this sentence do you see?

Answer (score -1):

You would say **less than** or **the lesser of**.  Not **lesser than**.

However, it largely depends on the sentence in which you're using your particular example, as it may be that using '**fewer than**' instead of '**less than**' is correct.

- 'Less' means not as much
- 'Fewer' means 'not as many'

For example, if I'm holding three apples I have '*fewer than 4 apples*'.

If I'm holding half a kilogram of sugar, I have '*less than a kilogram of sugar*'.

Here's a BBC article highlighting this often-made mistake:
http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/7591905.stm