# Lesser is to less, as ___ is to more? What's the equivalent of "morer"?

Tags: comparative

I'm resurrecting [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24719/difference-between-less-and-lesser#comment857949_24720).

1. What Syntactic Categories or terms distinguish "less" and "lesser"? "Comparative form" isn't the answer, because [*Less*, *lesser*, and *littler* are all comparative forms of *little*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/821).
2. What's the equivalent of "more" in terms of "lesser"? "Morer" doesn't exist in 2021 English.

Comment: In such things as bird names, it's _greater_. If _lesser_ is a comparative of _little_, _greater_ is a comparative of _great_ or _large_.

Comment: i'm not sure I'd use _lesser_ except in terms of animals or perhaps a geographical feature like a village or a hill, and Greater would be its opposite

Comment: "Greater" can be used as the opposite of "lesser" in several contexts. For example, you could choose "the lesser of two evils" or "the greater of two evils". Children who are not "of a lesser god" would presumably be "of a greater god". And so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lesser" is a *descriptive adjective*. This means it gives information about the nouns. In this case, the description is "inferior":

"*She plead guilty to the **lesser charge** of assault.*"

"*Hockey is wildly popular in Canada, and to a **lesser extent** in the US.*"

"*A **lesser man** would have kept that information to himself.*"

"Less", on the other hand, is a *[limiting adjective](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/limiting-adjective)*, which is a group of adjectives that "modify the nouns to which they are applied by restricting rather than describing or qualifying."

There is no "more" equivalent of "lesser", but as "lesser" means "inferior", a word with equivalent meaning is "superior".